# How to publish a (.pbix) report from Power BI Desktop directly to a Power BI Report Server (on-premises)

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-2016, power-bi-report-server

I've created a report in the "**Power BI Desktop optimized for Power BI Report Server (October 2017)**" app and want to deploy it directly to local Power BI Report Server instance but can't find a way to do that.

I found a page on Microsoft Docs called ["Quickstart: Create a Power BI report for Power BI Report Server"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-create-powerbi-report) and there is a Step 2.4 called "**Power BI Report Server Selection**" (below) that is a part of the **Get Data** wizard which I do not have in my case.

[image]

In my case I have **Get Data -> Analysis Services -> "SQL Server Analysis Server database" window -> "Navigator" window -> Ok** and that's all

Finally I had to just save .pbix file locally and upload it manually to **Power BI Report Server**.

Comment: Check this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986480/programmatically-deploying-power-bi-reports-to-power-bi-report-server-and-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save powerbi file directly to report server follow this steps:

*Power BI desktop report> **file**> **save as**> **Power BI report server**> provide your report server **portal url**> Provide your **file name**> click **ok** to sve it directly on report server*

[image: steps]

regards,
sanjay

Comment: Thank you @sanjay! Didn't notice this option :)